# Call to a member function move() on string Larael base64 encoded

Tags: laravel, base64, image-resizing

I'm getting photo from Android phone using API and base64encoded format.
After getting photo i must to resize it. But i'm getting error. Please help to solve it.

```
$image = $request->photo;  // my base64 encoded
$image = str_replace('data:image/jpg;base64,', '', $image);
$image = str_replace(' ', '+', $image);
$imagename = 'prsn-'.time().'.jpg';

$destinationPath = public_path('/thumbnail');
$img = Image::make($image);
$img->resize(150, 150, function ($constraint) 
{
    $constraint->aspectRatio();
  })->save($destinationPath.'/'.$imagename);
 $destinationPath = storage_path('local');
 $image->move($destinationPath, $imagename);  /***  <<<<<<< getting error on this line ***/

$input = $request->all();
$input['photo'] = $imagename;
Contact::create($input);
```

Comment: You have a string on the $image variable, so you can't use the move method on it. What about if you use `Image::make($image)->save(storage_path('local').'/'.$imagename);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved using belowed code

```
 $image = $request->photo;  // my base64 encoded
 $image = str_replace('data:image/jpg;base64,', '', $image);
 $image = str_replace(' ', '+', $image);
 $imagename = 'prsn-'.time().'.jpg';
 
 $destinationPath = public_path('/thumbnail');
 $img = Image::make($image);
 $img->resize(150, 150, function ($constraint) 
  {
     $constraint->aspectRatio();
  })->save($destinationPath.'/'.$imagename);
  $destinationPath = public_path('/images');
  Image::make($image)->save($destinationPath.'/'.$imagename);

  $input = $request->all();
  $input['photo'] = $imagename;
  Contact::create($input);
```

Thanks for all who want to help, special thank to: porloscerros-Ψ for advice and suggestion